# How do I $GET multiple values with the same name from a url?

Tags: php, get

I have created a form using checkboxes with the method set to GET.

The results are `example.com/careers/?career_type=val1&career_type=val2`

```
<?= $_GET['career_type']; ?>
```

This only displays val2.

Is it possible to display both values?

Comment: In your html, make `career_type` an array: `name="career_type[]"` so that you can iterate the list. The url to get will look something like: `career_type[]=baker&career_type[]=candlestick+maker` for the checked items.

Answer (score 1):

While it's perfectly valid to have multiple parameters with the same name, PHP doesn't handle it very well. You have two options.

1. Change the URL to use an array e.g. `example.com/careers/?career_type[]=va1&career_type[]=val2`.
   Then `$_GET['career_type']` will be returned as an array containing val1 and val2. If you're using a form to generate this URL, you can simply name your fields `name="career_type[]"`
2. If that's not possible, you can manually parse the query string. This will have the same effect:

```
    $query = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $params = [];
    foreach ($query as $param) {
        [$name, $value] = explode('=', $param, 2);
        $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
    }

    var_dump($params['career_type']);
```